# Model prediction validation – when to retrain?

Tags: machine-learning, validation

After a trained/tested model has been put in production, what's the best approach to keep track of the validity of the model such that one knows when to retrain?

Answer (score 1):

This is nearly impossible to answer without detailed A/B experiments, correcting for presentation bias at the same time.

Most large, moderns systems now use online training algorithms that can adart the learning rate in real time, on a per-channel basis, to compensate for this problem.

Comment: any examples of how such algorithms are used?